# Pasar argumentos incluyendolos en el fichero con python

Tags: python

Hola estoy chequeando un pequeño programa en python el cual yo le voy pasando una serie de argumentos desde consola. Pero ahora lo que quería hacer era poder poner estos argumentos desde el .py. Pongo un ejemplo sobre el código:

Codigo editado:

```
# Print the title
Header().first_title()

parser = MyParser()
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='Version ' + str(constant.CURRENT_VERSION), help='laZagne version')

# ------------------------------------------- Permanent options -------------------------------------------
# Version and verbosity 
PPoptional = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False,formatter_class=lambda prog: argparse.HelpFormatter(prog, max_help_position=constant.MAX_HELP_POSITION))
PPoptional._optionals.title = 'optional arguments'
PPoptional.add_argument('-v', dest='verbose', action='count', default=0, help='increase verbosity level')
PPoptional.add_argument('-path', dest='path',  action= 'store', help = 'path of a file used for dictionary file')
PPoptional.add_argument('-b', dest='bruteforce',  action= 'store', help = 'number of character to brute force')

# Output 
PWrite = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False,formatter_class=lambda prog: argparse.HelpFormatter(prog, max_help_position=constant.MAX_HELP_POSITION))
PWrite._optionals.title = 'Output'
PWrite.add_argument('-oN', dest='write_normal',  action='store_true', help = 'output file in a readable format')
PWrite.add_argument('-oJ', dest='write_json',  action='store_true', help = 'output file in a json format')
PWrite.add_argument('-oA', dest='write_all',  action='store_true', help = 'output file in all format')

# ------------------------------------------- Add options and suboptions to all modules -------------------------------------------
all_subparser = []
for c in category:
    category[c]['parser'] = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False,formatter_class=lambda prog: argparse.HelpFormatter(prog, max_help_position=constant.MAX_HELP_POSITION))
    category[c]['parser']._optionals.title = category[c]['help']

    # Manage options
    category[c]['subparser'] = []
    for module in modules[c].keys():
        m = modules[c][module]
        category[c]['parser'].add_argument(m.options['command'], action=m.options['action'], dest=m.options['dest'], help=m.options['help'])

        # Manage all suboptions by modules
        if m.suboptions and m.name != 'thunderbird':
            tmp = []
            for sub in m.suboptions:
                tmp_subparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False,formatter_class=lambda prog: argparse.HelpFormatter(prog, max_help_position=constant.MAX_HELP_POSITION))
                tmp_subparser._optionals.title = sub['title']
                if 'type' in sub:
                    tmp_subparser.add_argument(sub['command'], type=sub['type'], action=sub['action'], dest=sub['dest'], help=sub['help'])
                else:
                    tmp_subparser.add_argument(sub['command'], action=sub['action'], dest=sub['dest'], help=sub['help'])
                tmp.append(tmp_subparser)
                all_subparser.append(tmp_subparser)
            category[c]['subparser'] += tmp

# ------------------------------------------- Print all -------------------------------------------
parents = [PPoptional] + all_subparser + [PWrite]
dic = {'all':{'parents':parents, 'help':'Run all modules', 'func': runAllModules}}
for c in category:
    parser_tab = [PPoptional, category[c]['parser']]
    if 'subparser' in category[c]:
        if category[c]['subparser']:
            parser_tab += category[c]['subparser']
    parser_tab += [PWrite]
    dic_tmp = {c: {'parents': parser_tab, 'help':'Run %s module' % c, 'func': runModule}}
    dic = dict(dic.items() + dic_tmp.items())

#2- Main commands
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='Choose a main command')
for d in dic:
    subparsers.add_parser(d,parents=dic[d]['parents'],help=dic[d]['help']).set_defaults(func=dic[d]['func'],auditType=d)

# ------------------------------------------- Parse arguments -------------------------------------------
args = dict(parser.parse_args()._get_kwargs())
arguments = parser.parse_args()
start_time = time.time()
output()
verbosity()

# ------ Part used for user impersonation ------ 

currentUser = getpass.getuser()
argv = vars(arguments)['auditType']
current_filepath = sys.argv[0]
sids = ListSids()
isSystem = False
stopExecute = True
isChild = isChildProcess(current_filepath)
```

Hay alguna forma de agregar desde dentro del py el argumento que quiero poner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas, en general para hacer el traspaso de parametros vía consola se hace a través de la librería `getopt` que parsea las opciones del command line,
te muestro a través de un ejemplo.

El trozo de codigo que se quiere ejecutar se incluye dentro de una función main en el modulo que recibe `argv`, por ejemplo:

```
# uso: test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>
import sys, getopt
def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
         inputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
         outputfile = arg
   print 'Input file is "', inputfile
   print 'Output file is "', outputfile
```

Dentro del modulo se incluye el siguiente codigo que se ejecuta sólo al ejecutarse el modulo directamente:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Finalmente, si lo que quieres es ejecutar el modulo desde otro modulo de `.py`, simplemente importas el modulo con `import file`
y puedes pasarle los argumentos desde dentro así:

```
file.main("-i "file1" -o "file2"")
```

Ojalá haya sido esto lo que preguntase, en realidad me parece que tu pregunta le falta información en cuanto a la profundidad que le diste al problema.
Cualquier cosa edito mi respuesta, suerte!

Más información: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: perdona gracias por tu ayuda, voy a poner un poco de código sobre donde va los tiros de mi problema por si tienes alguna idea de como podría incluirlo desde el fichero python mi problema es que uso un parser pero quiero poner los argumentos desde el .py para notener que escribirlos desde el cmd.